# Scaffolder creates DATETIME instead of DATE, even when explicitly set to DATE by data annotations

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

I have encountered a nuisance where the MVC scaffolder sets the data type in the database to DATETIME when I in my model have set the datatype to DATE using data annotations. Any clues why?

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? my_date { get; set; }
```

I am using VS2012, MVC 4.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `DataTypeAttribute` makes sense only in regards of the UI representation of the field (when using the helper methods `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor`, for example).

Quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype.aspx) (highlight is mine):

> The DataTypeAttribute attribute lets you mark fields by using a type that is more specific than the database intrinsic types. For example, a string data field that contains e-mail addresses can be attributed with the EmailAddress type. **This information can be accessed by the field templates and modify how the data field is processed**.

It seems there is no reference to the actual database type used.

**EDIT: Fluent Mapping?**

Apparently EF also has the option of setting the DataType for a given property:  msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.10. I honestly never used it so if you wish to investigate and edit this answer with your findings it would be great! :)

Comment: Well, in that case, is there any way elegant way to avoid going into the DB, and manually changing all DATETIME to DATE? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You can possibly investigate the Fluent API for Mapping and Configuration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.10. I'll update the answer.